# How to protect source code in react-native app before passing the project to the client

Tags: react-native, obfuscation

For native apps, you can protect your source code by building a framework and access it like a blackbox.

For react-native app, is it possible to build the business logic or some components into something similar? (e.g. npm packages but how to hide the source code? The best way is to obfuscate the npm package with JScrambler?)

I'm building an app for a client, they didn't purchase the license to own the code. And they refuse to let us have access to their certs to publish the app, what are the alternatives to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that [offline bundle](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md#bundle) make the job:

For ios

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

For android

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --platform android --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

With `--dev false` it is obfuscated (`--minify true`) by default

Give your clients the `android` and `ios` folders for them to compile the native code themselves

Comment: If I run "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease" after your command above, is my code protected ? Thanks !

Comment: It at least will be obfuscated

Comment: Thanks for reply @Alexander ! But after run command "npx react-native bunde..." and build release. I still read content of index.android.bundle inside app-release.apk. Have you got ideas for me ?

Comment: Use `react-native ram-bundle` like one of the bellow answers suggested. I tried few npm packages without much success, but ram-bundle make the js bundle into non human readable text. https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.59/performance#enable-the-ram-format. If you find this comment useful, please mark the original bellow answer as useful.

Comment: @hdsenevi i don't see how `react-native ram-bundle` is protecting the source code, that seems to improve performance for large app instead of securing.

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo our team was recently reversed engineer by one pentester who claims he was capable to tamper our code and modify certain url. Hence I now doubt running the command share is enough (That's what we are doing too now). We don't have a solution yet, still looking for one now.

Answer (score 2):

For JavaScript code, the best option is probably obfuscation, and JScrambler probably works well. I do not know any other good solution than obfuscation for this particular issue.

I work on a team that just released a new JavaScript obfuscation product [JSDefender](https://www.preemptive.com/products/jsdefender/overview), and it has specific support for React Native that maybe you could try as an alternative to JScrambler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these scripts in your package.json. Also [it's](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/performance#enable-the-ram-format) [good for performance.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/performance#enable-the-ram-format)

```
"bundle-ios": "react-native ram-bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false",

"bundle-android": "react-native ram-bundle --entry-file index.js --platform android --dev false"
```

And I don't know which version of react you use, but if you use higher than 0.60.4, you should check [Hermes](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/hermes) which can be used for android, it converts your js to bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

**use the following obfuscator**

[react-native-obfuscating-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-obfuscating-transformer)